# Does this C code produce "undefined behavior"?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I'm reading an interesting article *[A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++, Part 1](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213)* on undefined behavior in C and C++. Often I do the following in my code:

```
int i = 10;
i = (++i) % 7;
```

Does this produce undefined behavior? On x86? ARM? Perhaps it depends on the compiler?

Comment: http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html

Comment: Also check out this [FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's undefined behavior because `i` is modified more than once without an intervening sequence point.

It depends on the compiler only in the sense that there are no requirements about what the code will do, so every compiler can do something different.  To be clear - <s>just because</s> even though you get results that seem to make sense (sometimes), the code is a bug.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer that was stuck at the bottom below the incorrect ones (including the accepted answer...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - as per standard ISO C.

- [Is this undefined C behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450582/c-programming-is-this-undefined-behavior)
- [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-abo)

[<strike>Though, a compiler is expected to produce consistent result.</strike>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059917/are-unspecified-and-undefined-behavior-required-to-be-consistent-between-compiles)

Comment: A compiler is not expected to produce anything consistent - you could most certainly get different results on different runs of code with undefined behavior. That might be somewhat unlikely with this particular UB, but there are no expectations nonetheless.

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing, I stand corrected. Will include more details in the answer.